# image processing to find vein pattern in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I have a problem about my image. Because I tried a lot of technique to find vein patterns. But, I could not find any solution. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img534/2320/6d2j.png

Comment: You should write more background such as ultimate goal of the study and what you have tried. Believe me. Writing a good question will help not only people answering but also the person asking.

Answer (score 2):

> Vein pattern recognition is one of the newest biometric techniques
>   researched today.  While the concept behind the method is quite
>   simple, there are various challenges to be found  throughout the
>   design and implementation of a vein scanning device concerning the
>   hardware lighting  system and the actual algorithms used for
>   processing the acquired images. In order to keep the scanning  errors
>   to a minimum the image acquired from the camera should be almost
>   noiseless and the algorithms  should be able to detect the vein
>   pattern in various real life conditions. Many implementations of this 
>   method are now in a commercial phase and there is a great need for a
>   system that can detect, analyze  and extract the correct human vein
>   pattern while keeping a low cost and reducing the computational  needs
>   of the image processing algorithms.  This paper will offer some
>   hardware implementation solutions based on our research and different 
>   algorithms will be discussed.

Septimiu Crisan, Ioan Gavril Tarnovan, Titus Eduard Crisan

More [here](http://home.mit.bme.hu/~kollar/IMEKO-procfiles-for-web/tc4/TC4-15th-Iasi-2007/Final_Papers/F060.pdf)

The first thing to do is understanding the problem, the read existing literature so maybe someone has done something similar or even tried to solve the problem already.
I would go reading state of art algorithms.